# Why vscode shows 'Call to unknown function' for posix_isatty(), posix_getpid() and others

Tags: php, posix

I am running vscode on Mac, editing files via SSH to a UBUNTU 20.04 system.

I find that use of well-documented functions such as **posix_getpid**(), **posix_isatty(STDIN)**, **posix_ppid()** and others generate a "call to undefined function" error with code PHP(PHP0417) [image: sample error]

Of course, the code executes without issue, but my deskcheck process always alerts me to this.  Is there some setting I need to use in vscode to indicate that the posix_* functions are OK? Or am I maybe doing something wrong in using posix_* stuff?

What must I do to clean up this error?

I am running PHP on the Mac system also.

```
> which php
/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/bin/php
dennis@macstudio:/Users/dennis   03/23 19:39:06
> php -v
PHP 7.4.29 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2022 11:36:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.29, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
dennis@macstudio:/Users/dennis   03/23 19:39:13
```

Comment: Do you have PHP installed locally? VSCode performs PHP validation using a local executable. That being said, since you're on Mac, the Posix functions should be available

Comment: Yes, I run PHP locally on this Mac system.  Question updated accordingly.

Comment: Can you try running something in the terminal like `php -r 'echo posix_getpid(), PHP_EOL;'`?

Comment: Thanks @Phil that seems to work.  Did that on the Mac.  Result.... > php -r 'echo posix_getpid(), PHP_EOL;'
23925

Comment: Check the path to the PHP executable in your vscode settings

Comment: @Phil you're a genius!  Solved!  Please post your latest comment as an answer; I will accept it.